# Merging multiple backlogs into a Visionary/Master backlog on JIRA?

Tags: planning, jira, backlog

**Context**

An enterprise AWS project with multiple Scrum teams building features.  Three additional stakeholder teams (Dev Ops, Operations, CISO) who send support and consultancy requests into the AWS Scrum team.

**Toolset**

JIRA / Confluence

**Problem**

Senior management at C-level would like a consolidated backlog of all teams in a Master backlog.

**Caveat/Complication**

Each Scrum team has a Product Owner with their own prioritized backlog so a **prioritized** Master backlog is not required.  Merely a planning view of everything.

**Solutions Considered**

1. Taking a JIRA extract weekly and merging all into an XLS table with filters
2. Using a PPT stakeholder deck with a Burn-Up slide for each Team and then a consolidated burn up as the final slide
3. Creating a JIRA Kanban Board, importing all backlogs and using the first To-Do column as a *backlog-lite* solution

**Question**

Is there a way of producing a consolidated backlog from multiple teams in JIRA without disturbing the order of those items on their native backlogs?

Comment: Create a(n agile) board in Jira and add all projects to them? That will display all backlogs. Use the (new) board's filter to adjust sorting for the overall backlog. That should keep the original prioritized order of the contributing backlogs intact. No guarantees. Haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider investigating plugins like Portfolio or Tempofolio which are designed exactly for higher management and provide a unified high level view to the separate backlogs. The plugins I mentioned are not free, but we were using them successfully in our organisation. I really recommend to check out the following short demo: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/portfolio/demo# 
Maybe this could help the C-level guys to have more visibility and transparency.

An alternative solution is basically to create a consolidated board. Boards in JIRA gather their issues based on JIRA filters assigned to them. Any working JIRA filter can be utilized by an Agile board. If your filter contains issues from more than one project so can the Agile board it's been assigned to. You can create the board just to see high level epics or stories and how you'll map the issue states to individual columns is up to you as well. I could imagine a simple TODO, IN PROGRESS, Released Kanban board for the high level management.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get all issues is to just use an empty JQL (the default when you use 'Issues->Search for Issues). If you need only *some*, then simply use '(project = "A" OR project = "B" OR ...)'. If you need it to be ordered by anything, just add the 'Order by' clause (ie. 'Order by project').

You can then Export it however you'd like. You can also save the filter for later use, so you do not need to keep recreating it. If you need it as a board in JIRA (for example, so you can run reports), just make a new board and set its filter to the one you made.